# Create a new Azure AD user via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create a new Azure AD user via PowerShell.
I created a global admin in the portal:
[image: global admin screenshot]

I run `Connect-MsolService` without any issues.

However, running `New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName ...` fails with insufficient permissions:
[image: error message]

Any idea what is the issue?

Comment: why not `New-AzureRMADUser`?

Comment: Well - almost. New-AzureRMADUser is missing some parameters (bug), like MailNickName.

Comment: How about `New-AzureADUser`? Isn't that the legacy-cmdlets (replaced msol-cmdlets)? The docs for MSOL-module says: "Note: this is the older MSOnline V1 PowerShell module for Azure Active Directory. Customers are encouraged to use the newer Azure Active Directory V2 PowerShell module instead of this module. For more information about the V2 module please see Azure Active Directory V2 PowerShell.". https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAD/2.0.0.98

Comment: Yes, I just tried that. I can connect but for some reason my global administrator gets a Forbidden.

Comment: Finally got it. You have to create an admin user in the classic portal and use that for authentication.

Comment: Ok it wasn't the classic bit it was using the directory name in the user principal name.

Comment: Frode F., would you please repost your comment as response? Then I can mark it as answer.

Comment: Both commands require the same permissions. Are you still unable to create users with the MSOL command? If so, it's probably a difference in how you're connecting to Azure AD. Frode's comment is a great recommendation, "follow the best practice guidance" though I wouldn't consider it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the login account for Connect-MsolService doesn't have sufficient permissions, for example, the account only has common user permissions, you might encounter the insufficient permissions problem.

However, if you create an account with Global administrator privileges in either new portal or classic portal, and use this account for login with Connect-MsolService, then you can create a new user by using the command 'New-MsolUser' successfully. Also, please note for the parameter '-UserPrincipalName', you must use the initial domain name for suffix, i.e. 'xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com', or the customized domain verified in AzureAD.

Currently, there are two PowerShell modules for Azure AD: **AzureAD** and **MSOnline**.

MSOnline is the old module, which can still provide functionality that is not yet available in the AzureAD module. In future, the older MSOnline module will be deprecated when all of the functionality has been migrated to the newer module - AzureAD.

Therefore, it's encouraged to use the newer AzureAD module.

More details about Azure AD PowerShell, please refer to the following documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/overview?view=azureadps-2.0